# Semantic UI change sidebar settings after initialization

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

My problem here is that it seems everytime I need to change some settings of my sidebar, I have to initiate it again, which causes it to change its context(reset settings to default).

How can I change a settings without initiating it?

Reference Doc : https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html

For example :

```
var sidebar = $('#sidebar').sidebar({context : '#context_div'}); //Initiating

$('#button1').click(function(){
    //sidebar({closeable : false}) this doesn't work
    sidebar.sidebar({closeable : false}) //this initiates it again, reseting the context
})

$('#button2').click(function(){
    sidebar.sidebar({closeable : true})
})
```

Comment: Does re-initializing it happen to add a class to the element that designates it as closeable false? If so on click you can update that element and add the className.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
sidebar.sidebar('setting', 'closable', false)
```